# UICollectionView Auto Resizing Results in Error

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview

I'm working on a toy app to investigate something else involving UICollectionView.  Because I *need* to (just accept the premise and move on) I'm trying to display text in the cells using auto layout.  For some reason after a certain point, the application starts failing with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x7fff532ebfd0)`.  I can't figure out why.

I'm not doing anything fancy.  Here's the estimated size code.

```
    if let cvl = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        cvl.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 40, height: 30)
    }
```

Here's the datasource method.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("reuse", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LabelCell

    let string = stCrispensDaySpeech[indexPath.row]

    cell.label.text = string
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    return cell

}
```

You can get the whole project at [furry-waddle tag](https://github.com/dpfannenstiel/furry-waddle/releases/tag/0.1).

Comment: Check reuse identifier that is being used is correct or not.

Comment: "reuse" is correct.  If was incorrect I would be crashing on that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your code and I found the problem:

The problem is when "," character appear, because the width of cell (minimum = 40)

Just change it your code like this:

```
    if let cvl = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        cvl.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 30)
    }
```

Comment: Nailed it!  Thanks.  (This incurs a separate error with layout on the last two words of the string.  Corrected by changing it to `CGSize(width: 10, height: 20)`).